# Loading an SVG into Processing.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, processing, processing.js

I am trying to import an SVG into a canvas using Processing.js. From what I have read this is easy in Processing as you simply add your SVG to a data folder, but I am having difficulty calling it into the canvas using Processing.js. I have attached an image with the area of the code where I think the concern is. Any help would be appreciated as I'm new to using SVGs in this manner.

Many thanks!

[image: loadShape screenshot]

UPDATE!!!

I have tested this in Processing IDE and it is working perfectly, but when it comes to Processing.js I am receiving the following errors in the Javascript console:

[image: Javascript console screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL is to be loaded directly from the filesystem by the browser(not using HTTP). *XMLHttpRequest* requires an HTTP server to supply the requested file. Put your file on an accessible HTTP server.

Comment: Thanks for your help @theNbomr. I knew it was something simple. All working now. Peace...